# Can you get 2 different results from a single MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

Can I retrieve 2 different (opposite) results from a single mysql query?

Instead of doing something like this in 2 separate queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT my_column FROM my_table WHERE id = 1";
/*if num_rows > 0, echo rows from $sql*/
$sql2 = "SELECT my_column FROM my_table WHERE id <> 1";
/*if num_rows > 0, echo rows from $sql2*/
```

Is it possible to do that in a single query?
Just asking to make sure, in case there's a better method out there to do my queries more efficiently.

Comment: No, how should that be possible?

Comment: yes, with a UNION

Comment: Sure, just do `SELECT my_column FROM my_table`

Comment: How would I differentiate between the two, in that case? I'd like to echo out rows from the positive query and the negative query.

Comment: Then `SELECT id, my_column FROM my_table` and when you loop results test to see if `id == 1` or not.

Comment: @AbraCadaver in a basic query that would be ok. But in a complex query, the values will be dynamic, so I can't always do a check inside the loop result. The sorting must come directly from the SQL query.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, but if you have an example...

Comment: Basically, the reason I'm currently doing it in 2 separate queries is because there is a while loop with HTML code that only exists if the num_rows of the first query returns at least 1 row. And there's another while loop with HTML code that only exists if the num_rows of the second query returns at least 1 row. Correct me if I'm wrong - this logic has to be done in two separate queries and cannot be done in a single query, right? Even if the two queries are the same except for a logical-operator.

Comment: @BillWhickomb which values would be dynamic?

Comment: its so much easier to read actual code, rather than an 'explanation' of code.

Comment: @Nick the id, in this example, would be a dynamic value which was from another sql query. This query is already about 3 levels deep (inside a while loop of results).

Comment: A query inside a loop always smells bad, its almost always not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the values in one query, you will need a way to distinguish the results from each other. Thus you need to select the `id` column as well. For ease of processing, you can also `ORDER BY id <> 1` (which will be 0 for id=1, 1 otherwise), which will give you all the results for `id = 1` first, followed by all the results for `id <> 1`:

```
SELECT id, my_column
FROM my_table
ORDER BY id <> 1
```

In terms of using this in PHP, you could do something like (assuming mysqli with a connection `$conn`):

```
$id_to_find = 4;
$last_id = 0;
$sql = "SELECT id, my_column FROM my_table ORDER BY id <> $id_to_find";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['id'] == $id_to_find) {
         // do something
    }
    else {
         if ($last_id == $id_to_find) {
              // output distinguishing line
         }
         // do something else
    }
    $last_id = $row['id'];
}
```

Because of the `ORDER BY` clause, this would do all the `somethings` before all the `something elses` which would have the same effect as performing the two queries sequentially.

Comment: This looks really potential, but I'm trying to figure out how to get the distinguishing line between the rows where id = 1 and those that <> 1. Remember that there could be more than 1 row, in both cases.

Comment: @BillWhickomb see my edit, this will allow you to output something between the two sets of data

Comment: Now, this is brilliant. What would you say, is this method or the two separate queries more efficient with regards to speed/scalability, considering that they provide nearly the exact same result?

Comment: @BillWhickomb that's a good question. There's an advantage to only performing one query, but then you lose because of the `ORDER BY` which could slow that query down, and also the extra logic needed in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all values from my_table, you may want to try just the

```
SELECT my_column FROM my_table
```

This will give all the values where id = 1 and id <> 1.